# Matching number and color in roulette simulator

Tags: excel, roulette-wheel-selection

I am trying to build an roulette game in Excel. Due to this [blog post](http://gamblingmath.blogspot.de/2015/01/simulating-roulette-in-excel.html) I am able to randomly select numbers that are provided in column D *Spin number*. Now I would like to auto-fill E, *Spin color* based on the columns B *Actual Number* and C *Color*.

For example: If D is 17 as in D3 (see below), the formula will look up 17 in B which is B10 and will provide the corresponding *Color* C10 in E *Spin Color* in E3. Therefore, 17 in D3 would lead to "Black" in E3.

As I am not very strong in Excel I would appreciate, if someone could provide an answer. Thank you so much!

Edit: With every new run the numbers in column D will change and E has to change accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Look into VLOOKUP, it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,$B$2:$C$11,2,false)
```

or with INDEX / MATCH (which is faster):

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH($D2,$B$2:$B$11,0))
```

Comment: Thank you Scott Craner & The TTG Guy